# DocuSign embed url not rendering in iFrame

Tags: iframe, http-headers, docusignapi, x-frame-options

Anyone ever had an issue when embeding a docusign signing ceremony in an iFrame?
I'm trying to test docusign embed signing by using an iFrame. But the browsers (`tested on Chrome, Firefox`) are refusing to render the url.

I get the embed url (which looks like `https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/XXXXXXXXX?slt=XXX`) from DocuSign and then sets this url to iFrame source on my website. But it just shows a blank page nothing comes up (**instead of embeding in an iframe if I just paste the url in the url bar it renders fine**). If I check the console logs in Google Chrome (on win10) I see an error 
`Refused to display 'https://account-d.docusign.com/recipient/auth?ui_locales=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'`.

```html
<iframe src='https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/XXXXXXXXX?slt=XXX' height='900' width='900'>
</iframe>
```

[image: iFrame blank page]

If I observe the network tab the following redirects are happening:

```
Request URL: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1/XXXXXXXXX?slt=XXX
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Response Headers
Location: https://account-d.docusign.com/managed_token/v1/redeem/?slt=XXX


Request URL: https://account-d.docusign.com/managed_token/v1/redeem/?slt=XXX
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Response Headers
Location: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?code=XXX
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN


Request URL: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?code=XXX
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Response Headers
Location: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/ActivateSecurityChecks.aspx?insession=1&ti=XXX

Request URL: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/ActivateSecurityChecks.aspx?insession=1&ti=XXX
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Response Headers
Set-Cookie: BIGipDocuSign_Demo_Signing=XXX
X-DocuSign-Node: XXX

Request URL: https://account-d.docusign.com/recipient/auth?ui_locales=en
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Response Headers
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: XXX
X-DocuSign-Node: XXX
```

*Note: I followed [this](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg001EmbeddedSigningController.cs) sample from docusign's official examples.*

***EDIT***
RecipientViewRequest:

```
{
    "AssertionId":"logging in event id", 
    "AuthenticationInstant":"1\/29\/2020 11:09:26 AM", 
    "AuthenticationMethod":"password", 
    "ClientUserId":"logged in user id", 
    "Email":"my-email@mydomain.com", 
    "ReturnUrl":"https:\/\/subdomain.mydomain.com\/recieve", 
    "UserName":"signerFirst lastName", 
    "XFrameOptions":"allow_from", 
    "XFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl":"https:\/\/subdomain.mydomain.com"
}
```

***EDIT 2***
If I recall, the embeding method had worked for me in the past while testing. 
This behavior of refusing to render in iFrame has started fairly recently. Maybe they have changed on their end during last month.

Comment: are you using Chrome? what version?

Comment: I don't think version matters. If that does here's the info: `Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: what URL did you use in the xFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In general, iframes are discouraged due to compatibility and difficulty in troubleshooting. The recommendation is to instead redirect the user to the URL and then catch the returnUrl redirect upon completing.

That said, there are two relevant parameters in the [Envelopes::CreateRecipientView](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) call

```
"xFrameOptions": "allow_from",
"xFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl": "https://example.com"
```

where the xFrameOptions parameter should be "allow_from" to enable this functionality, and AllowFromUrl should be the domain of your site.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for your prompt response. I'll be back and let you know after setting these two properties.

Comment: getting the same blank page. Here's my `RecipientViewRequest`
`
{
    "AssertionId":"logging in event id", 
    "AuthenticationInstant":"1\/29\/2020 11:09:26 AM", 
    "AuthenticationMethod":"password", 
    "ClientUserId":"logged in user id", 
    "Email":"my-email@mydomain.com", 
    "ReturnUrl":"https:\/\/subdomain.mydomain.com\/recieve", 
    "UserName":"signerFirst lastName", 
    "XFrameOptions":"allow_from", 
    "XFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl":"https:\/\/subdomain.mydomain.com"
}
`

Comment: On a similar question, Inbar mentioned that you may need to add the x-frame-options to _your_ page. Check his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971601

Comment: Like a meta html tag? I have two test sites one with X-Frame-Option for itself and other without any security headers. Didn't work for both. I'll add one more interesting thing about this behavior in the Q.