# Docusign Refused to display

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement embedded DocuSign sender view, I am using the node SDK to get the URL and display it in the Iframe, the problem is that when I try to open it, I get the following error.

[Docusign Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRPIT.png)

This happens in Safari v13.

Anyone who has gone through the same thing that can help me?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate question and should have the same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970661/docusign-embed-url-not-rendering-in-iframe/59971122?noredirect=1#comment106059307_59971122

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers protect you against using a page in an iframe that comes from a different domain. 
to overcome this you have to tell the browser that it's safe and you are OK with this.
Add this to your top HTML page:

```
"xFrameOptions": "allow_from",
"xFrameOptionsAllowFromUrl": "https://docusign.net"
```

Comment: how should you add this like a meta? do you have an example?

Comment: it depends what you use for your web server. see here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: but there mention that allow-from is obsolete and it's not supported by Safari

Comment: does this issue only happen in Safari? does Chrome work ok?

Comment: yes, only in safari happens, in chrome and other browsers works correctly.

Comment: are you actually trying to embed the member page inside an iframe? not embedded signing?

Comment: I'm trying to embed the sender view, I got The URL from Envelopes::createSenderView https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender#sdkmethod

Comment: yes, but what is the URL that you are trying to show in the iframe? in the image you shared in the question it shows a member URL

Comment: This is an URL that I'm Docusign get me to show in Iframe https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=2301b494-1bf8-4e77-972f-e88c85d87cab&DocuEnvelope=f1965a71-87be-4002-acfe-ec2828b8efe0&send=1

Comment: can you try to open this URL in the top frame, no an iframe and show a screenshot of what it shows? Something is not making sense to me.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ThHLwBn this is what I'm trying to open in the iframe

Comment: ok, so here is a see different URL from what you mentioned above. Did you get this URL From API call or you just opened the web tool directly?

Comment: This URL is what I get from the API using the method http://docusign.github.io/docusign-node-client/module-api_EnvelopesApi.html#createEditView

Comment: are you using latest version of Safari? can you check for SameSite cookies settings?